# I could not add persistent volume claim to Spark application

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have tried below approach

```
spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.claimName=OnDemand
spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.storageClass=gp2
spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.sizeLimit=40Gi
spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.mount.path=/data
spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.mount.readOnly=false
```

It throws below exception

```
    ERROR DiskBlockManager: Failed to create local dir in /data. Ignoring this directory.
java.io.IOException: Failed to create a temp directory (under /data) after 10 attempts!
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.createDirectory(Utils.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.$anonfun$createLocalDirs$1(DiskBlockManager.scala:145)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.flatMap(ArrayOps.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.createLocalDirs(DiskBlockManager.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockManager.<init>(DiskBlockManager.scala:43)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:394)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createExecutorEnv(SparkEnv.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$7(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
```

I have not used pvc claim for spark driver pod.
can you help me?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I think the problem with me is that the worker nodes don't have SSH enabled and I haven't found a way to enable them since they are very minimal installation of Linux and have no SSH or package manager installed. When I try to mount a PV, the nodes should also create a directory that they can't for some reason and give me a permission error.

Comment: In your case, maybe try changing the `ownership` of the `/data` directory? The nodes might have different ownership and /data dir has different?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I still think it is worth mentioning it.

1. I agree that it can be as easy as the /data directory does not exist. I tried with the /mnt folder which exists and was still having the same problem. You can actually create a new docker image with new folder if you really want to use /data. Use the current image as a base image and modify it to your needs.
2. I actually solved the problem by setting the --set webhook.enable=true flag while installing the spark-operator. You can read the whole thread here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/issues/455